# Change Font(Text) Color using Color Picker in Vue js

Tags: vue.js

I want to change font(text) color when user pick it from color picker,I had made this but it wont work,

```html
<textarea :class="changeColor"></textarea>
<v-color-picker class="ma-2" hide-inputs @click="changeColor('color')"></v-color-picker>
 changeColor(val){ this.color = val}
```

[image: Image of what I want to achieve when user select color]

Comment: Your changing the color value of the property `color`. Yet you do not assign the color to the textarea nor change the class `changeColor`. You have a bit of a mix up there. Can you please share the complete code of your component ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To dynamically assign a css color value to a html element you can use `:style="{}"` . 
Like this

```
<template>
<div>
   <textarea :style="{color:color}"></textarea>
   <v-color-picker v-model="color" />
</div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        color : '#FFFFFF'
      }
    }
  } 
</script>
```

Comment: Awesome @ObossChacha ! Glad I could help :)=